# How to convert array to object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to convert the following array:

```js
const data = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]];
```

to the following object:

```js
const data = [
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 4
  },
  {
    a: 5,
    b: 6,
    c: 7,
    d: 8
  },
  {
    a: 9,
    b: 10,
    c: 11,
    d: 12
  }
];
```

How do I do it using loop or some other way, of course?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet that you're having trouble with? I'd suggest you start by looking at `Array.prototype.map` and `Array.prototype.reduce`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a basic map / reduce operation where you [*map*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the outer array to a new one where each value (array) is [*reduced*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to a single object.

Given the simple nature of each value (a single array with four values), you can skip `Array.prototype.reduce()` for some [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring).

For example

```js
const data = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]];

const newData = data.map(([ a, b, c, d ]) => ({ a, b, c, d }))

console.info(newData)
```

Note that this really hinges on knowing the data structure and no surprises (more or fewer elements in each array for example).

---

If you wanted a much more robust version, you'll want something like this

```js
const data = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12]];

const newData = data.map(arr => arr.reduce((obj, val, idx) => ({
  ...obj,
  [String.fromCharCode(97 + idx)]: val
}), Object.create(null)))

console.info(newData)
```

The only thing to worry about here is if your arrays contain more than 26 elements. Then your object keys are going to get weird.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) combined with [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Code:

```js
const alphabet = [...'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'];
const data = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]];
const reasult = data.map(arr => arr.reduce((a, c, i) => (a[alphabet[i]] = c, a), {}));

console.log(reasult);
```